# Magento using 2nd DB for Media - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Magento across 7 servers on AWS
4 HTTPD
1 Memcached
1 Main DB
1 Media DB

Uploading an image works, loads the thumbnail in the admin, then when saving it results in an error:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.core_file_storage' doesn't exist

I know the table is there. I can see it.
core_file_storage   ~471,510    InnoDB  utf8_general_ci     2.1 GiB

Any ideas? Any ideas at all to bounce around?

---Edit

The SQL error no longer appears, it saves successfully but the image is empty.

---Calling on the second DB with local.xml with:

```
    <media_storage>
        <connection>
            <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
            <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
            <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
            <dbname><![CDATA[magento]]></dbname>
            <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
            <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
            <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
            <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
            <active>1</active>
        </connection>
    </media_storage>
```

Comment: Magento is not looking in the other database, instead its looking inside the same database where the magento is installed. You need to check the settings where you are telling magento to save images in order database

Comment: In Config > System it's set to the DB in the pulldown. It also synced too. The media DB is stated in local.xml

Comment: You're right, the main DB doesn't have that table. Now why is it trying to get into the wrong DB in admin uploads? Everything is working great otherwise.

Comment: Also keep in mind the error stopped, it all uploads now, and shows green that it saved successfully. Yet the image is a dead link.

Comment: Seems the upload is only successful on one of the 4 servers under the load balancer. Not sure why. This is frustrating.

Comment: $$$ if someone can help.

Comment: did you ever get this figured out? seems like I'm having the same issue in 1.9.2.0

Comment: Hey @Dan, did you ever find out the solution to this problem?
Still the same issue on Magento 1.9.2.X... Did you patch something up?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and (one way or another) got the tables created in the main database (as well as my media database).  This masked the real problem (why was Magento looking for these tables in the wrong database) but everything appeared to be working.  Until ...

If you attempt to upload more than one image at a time, only the first image was properly stored.  And if you attempted to use the same filename for a different product these would not work either.  Ultimately, I decided to do some debugging and what I found was that the file gets reloaded from the table and calls setData($row) to populate it on the current instance.  When it does this Magento clears out the connection name (which is also stored in the data array) and in your case would have formerly been called "media_storage".

When it attempts to do a save of this model it fails because it is now using the wrong connection and those tables do not exist.  If you have done the workaround and they DO exist, the functionality obviously doesn't exist and you are left with missing thumbnails.  If you check your media database you will see rows for each file, but only the first one has been renamed out of "tmp".

My solution (for now) is to add the following method to Mage/Core/Model/File/Storage/Database/Abstract.php.  This ensures that after a setData it will reset the connection name (if it was populated).  I have only briefly tested this, but so far it appears to have done the trick and both issues I was experiencing have been resolved.

```
/**
 * Ensure that the connection name is retained if the set data is setting the entire row.
 */
public function setData($key, $value=null)
{
    $connectionName = $this->getConnectionName();
    parent::setData($key, $value);
    $this->setConnectionName($connectionName);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Ever found a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Solution above does not work anymore in Magento > 1.9. What works for me :

    public function setData($key, $value=null)
    {
        $connectionName = $this->getConnectionName();
        if (empty($connectionName)) {
            $connectionName = $this->getConfigConnectionName();
        }
        parent::setData($key, $value);
        parent::setData('connection_name', $connectionName);
        $this->_getResource()->setConnectionName($connectionName);
        return $this;
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you will be using filesystem storage, **Make sure your /media directory is set to 777 and also run `chmod -R o+w media`**. If the error persists, the cleanest way to solve the problem is as follows:

1. Go to SYSTEM>CONFIGURATION>ADVANCED>SYSTEM and switch "Storage Configuration for Media" to "Database". Click SYNCHRONIZE. Wait for the synchronization process to finish or time out (likely, depending on your settings). The table "core_directory_storage" has been created and filled up. Click on SAVE CONFIG (not sure if this step is necessary, but do it anyways).
2. If the synchronization process timed out, you will likely see a notification about a major error in the Magento Admin "An error has occured while syncronizing media storages.". It doesn't matter because in the next step we are reverting back to file based media storage.
3. In the same setting adjusted in step #1, switch back to "File System" and click SYNCHRONIZE again. Click on SAVE CONFIG (not sure if this step is necessary, but do it anyways).
4. Now go to your DB Manager (PHPMyAdmin for example) and delete all rows in the recently created table using DELETE FROM `core_directory_storage`.

Your *table missing* error is now gone.